# OrientDB doesn't save edge in/out and properties

Tags: distributed, orientdb

I've installed orientdb in distributed mode but I have a problem during creation of the edges (lightweightmode is disabled).

When I create an edge everything seems to work fine but actually orientdb doesn't save the properties and even the link between out-in objects!

I run the server executing **dserver.sh**. 
If I run the server with **server.sh** the edges are created correctly.

I've tried to do it within a transaction but it didn't work.

An example:

```
orientdb {db=dmd2}> create vertex set name = 'Mario'

Created vertex 'V#9:0{name:Mario} v1' in 0.010000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=dmd2}> create vertex set name = 'Luigi'

Created vertex 'V#9:1{name:Luigi} v1' in 0.008000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=dmd2}>

orientdb {db=dmd2}> select from v

----+----+------+-----
#   |@RID|@CLASS|name
----+----+------+-----
0   |#9:0|V     |Mario
1   |#9:1|V     |Luigi
----+----+------+-----

2 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.008 sec(s).
orientdb {db=dmd2}>

orientdb {db=dmd2}> create edge from #9:0 to #9:1 set type = 'Friend'

Created edge '[E#10:0{type:Friend,out:#9:0,in:#9:1} v3]' in 0.030000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=dmd2}>

orientdb {db=dmd2}> select from v

----+----+------+-----+--------+--------
#   |@RID|@CLASS|name |out_    |in_
----+----+------+-----+--------+--------
0   |#9:0|V     |Mario|[size=1]|null
1   |#9:1|V     |Luigi|null    |[size=1]
----+----+------+-----+--------+--------

2 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.006 sec(s).
orientdb {db=dmd2}>

orientdb {db=dmd2}> select from e

----+-----+------
#   |@RID |@CLASS
----+-----+------
0   |#10:0|E
----+-----+------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.003 sec(s).
orientdb {db=dmd2}> select expand(out()) from v where name = 'Luigi'


0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.005 sec(s).
orientdb {db=dmd2}>
```

Nothing appears on the server log.
The nodes are two. I did some test also with only a single node up and running with the same result..

Thank you very much.

Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been already fixed in 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT (tomorrow released as final).

Comment: I created the database in the first node started with server.sh. Then I restart the first node with dserver.sh and then the second node with dserver. Automatically the first node shared its content with second node and the issue didn't appear anymore.. (version 2.0.2)